# tmpl is not defined jquery.slider.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reference, slider

I have this website which uses. angular-awesome-slider.min.js
It works as it should how ever I keep seeing 
referenceerror tmpl is not defined jquery.slider.js 169:4

Any ideas how to resolve this? Google my friend could not answer this question.

Comment: Sounds like a minor bug in `jquery.slider.js` - is that your code or a library?

Comment: was a library. I found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it.

I removed jquery.slider.js

(cannot post a script tag obviously)

You only need to add:

angular-awesome-slider.min.js and .css not the jquery slider. I thought it needed it. My bad.